# Function and patterns. FixedPointList doesn't work with function

Tags: functions, function-construction, programming

There is a function:

```
Clear[sort]; sort[{a___, b_, c_, d___}] := {a, c, b, d} /; b > c;
```

It perfectly works with NestList function:

```
NestList[sort, {5, 4, 3, 2, 1}, 10]
{{5, 4, 3, 2, 1}, {4, 5, 3, 2, 1}, {4, 3, 5, 2, 1}, {3, 4, 5, 2, 
  1}, {3, 4, 2, 5, 1}, {3, 2, 4, 5, 1}, {2, 3, 4, 5, 1}, {2, 3, 4, 1, 
  5}, {2, 3, 1, 4, 5}, {2, 1, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}
```

But it isn't working with FixedPointList:

```
FixedPointList[sort, {5, 4, 3, 2, 1}]
```

It seems like infinite loop, the program just evaluating something without stop. What's the reason of such behaviour and how can I fix my function to make it work?

Comment: Look at `NestList[sort, {5, 4, 3, 2, 1}, 13]` and you should see why FixedPointList never finishes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `sort` doesn't evaluate when the list is ordered. See what happens when you increase the nesting:

```
NestList[sort, {5, 4, 3, 2, 1}, 12]
```

> {{5, 4, 3, 2, 1}, {4, 5, 3, 2, 1}, {4, 3, 5, 2, 1}, {3, 4, 5, 2, 1}, {3, 4, 2,
>      5, 1}, {3, 2, 4, 5, 1}, {2, 3, 4, 5, 1}, {2, 3, 4, 1, 5}, {2, 3, 1, 4, 
>     5}, {2, 1, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, sort[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}], 
>    sort[sort[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}]]}

Notice that after the list is sorted, further nesting just adds more sort wrappers. You can fix this by giving `sort` a definition for ordered inputs:

```
Clear[sort];
sort[{a___, b_, c_, d___}] := {a, c, b, d} /; b>c
sort[a_?OrderedQ] := a
```

Then:

```
FixedPointList[sort, {5, 4, 3, 2, 1}]
```

> {{5, 4, 3, 2, 1}, {4, 5, 3, 2, 1}, {4, 3, 5, 2, 1}, {3, 4, 5, 2, 1}, {3, 4, 2,
>      5, 1}, {3, 2, 4, 5, 1}, {2, 3, 4, 5, 1}, {2, 3, 4, 1, 5}, {2, 3, 1, 4, 
>     5}, {2, 1, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}

Comment: Thanks, Carl Woll! I thought that situation like that exists, but didn't know how to fix it.